# C++ program gives junk at first try but gives proper value if it catches an exception and retries

Tags: c++, c++11

The program gives junk value in the first try that is if it didn't caught any exception but when an exception is found and it retries the program gives proper and correct output. How do I correct the output for the input it gets the first time(i.e. first input without exception...).
The program is to convert Binary to decimal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int check() {
    long int bin;
    cout<<"Enter the binary number : ";
    cin>>bin;
    long int temp=bin;int len,t,sum=0;
    while(temp!=0) {
        temp=temp/10;
        len++;
    }
    temp=bin;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        if(temp%10==0 || temp%10==1)
            temp=temp/10;
        else
            throw(0);
    }
    temp=bin;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        t=temp%10;
        sum+=t*pow(2,i);
        temp=temp/10;
    }
    cout<<"The decimal equivalent is "<<sum<<"."<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    string a[10];int cont;
    a[0]="<--Invalid Input. Please enter proper binary number(0s & 1s).-- 
    >\n";
    try {
        check();
    }
    catch(int e_c) {
        cout<<a[e_c];
        cout<<"To try again press 1 else 0."<<endl;
        cin>>cont;
        if(cont==1) {
            try {
                check();
            }
            catch(int e_c) {
                cout<<"Wrong input!!!\n\nX_Terminating Program._X\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Output with junk value and proper input at first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuzFC.png)
[Exception is caught and on retrying output is proper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E2rB.png)

Comment: Have you used a debugger to investigate?

Comment: Yes. this is what it showed, I don't really know what it means.

Comment: Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
Child process PID: 1112
[Inferior 1 (process 1112) exited normally]
Debugger finished with status 0

Comment: I'd suggest googling "gdb tutorial" and working through it.  It's never too early to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: I'll do that, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 major errors in your program. When you compile your program, you should make sure to turn on errors and warnings, and it will point out these issues before you ever run the first time.

When I compile your program I get the following result from the compiler:

> main.cpp:35:1: error: control may reach end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
>
> ```
> }
> ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:19:9: warning: variable 'len' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
>
> ```
>     len++;
>     ^~~
> ```
>
> main.cpp:16:30: note: initialize the variable 'len' to silence this warning
>
> ```
> long int temp=bin;int len,t,sum=0;
>                          ^
>                           = 0
> ```

You're never initializing the `len` variable in the `check()` function, so it contains random junk. Furthermore, even if you were initializing it, your `check()` function doesn't have a `return` statement, so whatever it calculates is lost and random junk is returned to the caller.

The compiler gives you a suggestion of how to fix the `len` issue. You probably want to return `sum` from `check()`.

Comment: Yes it worked. It was a dumb mistake. I made the function void instead of int. Thank you very much.